# Clubs in regular cardinal, give function

Tags: set-theory

Given regular cardinal $\kappa > \omega$ and a closed unbounded set $C \subseteq \kappa$. Give a function $f : \kappa \rightarrow \kappa$ s.t. if $\forall \beta < \alpha [f(\beta) < \alpha]$, then $\alpha \in C$.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, this is not a question. You might want to edit it and make it into one. While you're at it, include what you'd done as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: You need to be sure that whenever $\alpha\in\kappa\setminus C$, there is a $\beta<\alpha$ such that $f(\beta)\ge\alpha$. In fact we can just as easily define $f$ so that if $\alpha\in\kappa\setminus C$, there is a $\beta<\alpha$ such that $f(\beta)>\alpha$. Try doing this in such a way that if $\alpha\in C$, then $f(\beta)\le\alpha$ for each $\beta\le\alpha$. If you still can’t find a function that works, mouse over the spoiler-protected block for one; you’ll have to prove that it actually works, and for this you’ll definitely need to use the fact that $C$ is closed.

> Let $f(\alpha)=\min\{\gamma\in C:\gamma\ge\alpha\}$.